# Unable to get the match property of the WorkSheet function class - Syntax?

Tags: excel, vba, match

I keep getting this error on the line with `Application.WorksheetFunction` and from reading on the topic for hours I feel that I've gotten just about nowhere.
Does it have something to do with the way I'm referencing Sheet2? Or am I not understanding fully what `Application.WorksheetFunction` is supposed to do?

```
Sub SearchForValues()

i = 4   'starts the iterator at column D

Do While Cells(1, i) <> ""

    Dim l As Long, searchRange As String
    n = 2
        Do While Range("A" & n) <> ""      'loop until the last row of data in the first column
        StartRow = Range("B" & n)
        EndRow = Range("C" & n)
        searchRange = "A" & StartRow & ":Q" & EndRow
        l = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Cells(1, i), Worksheets("Sheet2").Range(searchRange), 0)
        Range("D" & n) = l
        n = n + 1
    Loop

i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Here's a screenshot of the data I have. Columns B and C are the ranges of rows that I want to search in on Sheet2 for each row on sheet 1 and each cell across the top is a term I want to search for in that range.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Match only works on 1 dimensional arrays; either one row or one column.

Comment: @ScottCraner this makes a lot of sense, thank you. Is there a different function I can use in order to search an entire range?

Comment: Use the VBA Find()

Comment: Your code is a bit of a mess.  You can use `Range.Find` instead of `Match`.  From your image it looks like you want to fill `True` or `False` in `E2:H?` if the column headers in `E1:H1` are found within specific ranges.  However, you just keep overwriting the values in Column D. What values do you want in Column D?

Answer (score 1):

Scott Craner already answered your question in his comments with "
Match only works on 1 dimensional arrays; either one row or one column" and "Use the VBA Find()".

Here is an example of how you can use `Range.Find`

```
Sub SearchForValues()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim Target As Range
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        For x = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            For y = 4 To .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                Set Target = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & .Cells(x, "B").Value & ":Q" & .Cells(x, "C").Value)
                .Cells(x, y).Value = Not Target.Find(.Cells(1, y).Value) Is Nothing
            Next
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```